# select_sum and num_rows not working together in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Here is my query. I want to get total sum of quantity and num of records in that.

```
 function getCountByType($inventory_type) {

        $this->db->select_sum('quantity','total_quantity');
        if($inventory_type)       
        $this->db->where('inventory_type',$inventory_type);
        $query = $this->db->get($this->tableInventory);
        $resultdata = $query->result(); 
        $result['total_count'] = $query->num_rows();
        $result['total_quantity'] = $resultdata[0]->total_quantity;
        return $result;
    }
```

It gives me right sum of quantity but `num_rows` returns `1` every time. even if I have `10` records it gives only `1` record and when I `remove` `select_sum` it will work fine.

Comment: can you post the the table structure of your tables

Comment: i have tbl_inventory
in which fields are inventory_id, quantity, cost, add_time
inventory_id is primary key

Comment: what do you mean with total quantity and total count? isn't it the same?

Comment: total_quantity means sum of all quantity and total count means total records count in table 
both are not same

Comment: In SQL, `SELECT SUM(quantity) FROM mytable` will return just one row -- the sum of all the quantities. I expect that's what's happening under the covers.

Answer (score 0):

Sum is aggregate function which grouped your row into single put sum query at last.

```
function getCountByType($inventory_type) {
        if($inventory_type)       
        $this->db->where('inventory_type',$inventory_type);
        $query = $this->db->get($this->tableInventory);
        $resultdata = $query->result(); 
        $result['total_count'] = $query->num_rows();
        $this->db->select_sum('quantity','total_quantity');
        $result['total_quantity'] = $resultdata[0]->total_quantity;
        return $result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`select_sum` means it will give you the summary of all the rows, not individual one.

You need to do either two queries, or calculate the sum your self (suggest)

Answer (score 0):

`SUM()` is an `aggregate` function. It takes all the rows that are returned for a group and adds them up.

Since you do not have a `GROUP BY` clause, it is adding up the values of all rows, even if there are none. It is then returning the total as a single row, so there should only be `1 row.`

You can use `group_by` to get total number of `row` like

```
        $this->db->select_sum('quantity','total_quantity');
        if($inventory_type)       
        $this->db->where('inventory_type',$inventory_type);
        $this->db->group_by('YOUR_COLUMN');
        $query = $this->db->get($this->tableInventory);
        $resultdata = $query->result(); 
        $result['total_count'] = $query->num_rows();
        $result['total_quantity'] = $resultdata[0]->total_quantity;
        return $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you wanted total counts and total total_quantity. 
Just replace the line `$this->db->select_sum('quantity','total_quantity');` with this

```
$this->db->select('SUM(quantity) total_quantity,COUNT(quantity) total_count');
```

Now You can get them this way (after `$resultdata = $query->result();`)

```
$result['total_count'] = $resultdata[0]->total_count;
$result['total_quantity'] = $resultdata[0]->total_quantity;
```

**Note**

you can use this because the result will return one record

```
$resultdata = $query->row();
$result['total_count']=$resultdata->total_count;
$result['total_count']=$resultdata->total_quantity;
```